# Why does Chrome ignore local jQuery cookies?

Tags: jquery, cookies, google-chrome

I am using the jQuery Cookie plugin ([download](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) and [demo](http://stilbuero.de/jquery/cookie/) and [source code with comments](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt)) to set and read a cookie. I'm developing the page on my **local machine**.

The following code will successfully set a cookie in FireFox 3, IE 7, and Safari (PC). But **if the browser is Google Chrome AND the page is a local file**, it does not work.

```
$.cookie("nameofcookie", cookievalue, {path: "/", expires: 30});
```

**What I know**:

- The plugin's [demo](http://stilbuero.de/jquery/cookie/) works with Chrome.
- If I put my code on a web server (address starting with http://), it works with Chrome.

So the cookie fails only **for Google Chrome on local files**.

**Possible causes**:

- Google Chrome doesn't accept cookies from web pages on the hard drive (paths like file:///C:/websites/foo.html)
- Something in the plugin implentation causes Chrome to reject such cookies

Can anyone confirm this and identify the root cause?

Comment: When you say the demo works, do you mean if you save it to your hard drive and access it like file://?

Comment: No - just accessing the link above with Chrome.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Chrome doesn't support cookies for local files (or, like Peter Lyons mentioned, localhost*) unless you start it with the --enable-file-cookies flag. You can read a discussion about it at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535.

*Chrome *does* support cookies if you use the local IP address (127.0.0.1) directly. so in the localhost case, that could be an easier workaround.

Comment: Setting the domain to the IP did not work for me, but it worked if I removed the domain (locally, we need the domain for production)

Comment: On Mac OSX to start Chrome with the flag --enable-file-cookies use a terminal comnad:  'open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --enable-file-cookies' - (or tweak it according to your Chrome.app location)

Answer (score 7):

For local applications use localStorage in Chrome instead:
 http://people.w3.org/mike/localstorage.html

Answer (score 6):

i had some problem and solved it this terrible solution.
using store and cookie plugin together.

```
<script src="js/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Storage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

//get cookies
var helpFlag=(is_chrome)?$.Storage.get("helpFlag"):$.cookies.get("helpFlag");

//set cookies
if(is_chrome)$.Storage.set("helpFlag", "1");else $.cookies.set("helpFlag", "1");
```

I know that this isnt perfect solution but works for me

Answer (score 6):

This did the job for me:

[image]

Right click on your Chrome Icon and select Properties, Shortcut tab and add --enable-file-cookies at the last of the target path.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, please try using the IP address of localhost instead. For e.g  "http://127.0.0.1/yoursite/"

Answer (score 3):

please check out [Cookies & Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html).

```
$.cookie("nameofcookie", cookievalue, {path: "/", expires: 30});
```

change this line to

```
$.cookie("nameofcookie", cookievalue, {*Path:* "/", expires: 30});
```

this project working is fine.

Comment: Thanks, changing the case to "Path" fix my problem

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause is the `path: "/"`, since you're not using a normal web URL, `/` probably doesn't mean much - try without setting the path at all.

Comment: Good thought, but '/' is the default anyway. I tried 'file:///C:/' but I think that's nonsense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

If you use chrominum this is the command to enable local cookies

> chromium-browser --enable-file-cookies

It's the same thing for chrome

Hope this help you !

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can use Tampermonkey with access to local files ( [How to include Local htm pages in a Tampermonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437050/how-to-include-local-htm-pages-in-a-tampermonkey-script) )
By that way you will use Tampermonkey's storage, and will be able to set and get your data  by functions GM_getValue(data) and GM_setValue(data). I used that for my local HTML page, which i used as customizable alternative to Windows Explorer

But actually [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) from [Yuri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2483762/9130324) works perfect.