# Javascript cookie removal not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome

I'm using javascript to remove a cookie but for some reason it isn't working with Chrome. The script I'm using is;

```
function clearCookie()
{
   document.cookie = 'myCookie=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT; path=/myPath/';
}
```

This works on;

- IE 8.0.6
- Firefox 3.6.12

..but doesn't work on Chrome 7.0.517.44, after the cookie is supposed to be cleared I can still see it and the value hasn't changed.

Any ideas? Are there any user settings in Chrome that might prevent my cookie from being removed?

Comment: I don't know about chrome, so this is just a guess. Maybe chrome caches the view of cookies? Or: What happens after you quit chrome and reopen it? Is the cookie still there?

Comment: The cookie expires when the session ends, so yes, closing the browser and reopening clears it.

Comment: Also try to navigate to a different page on the same domain after you clear the cookie - does the cookie still exist?

Comment: Yeah, it does, that's the problem :(

Answer (score 2):

Chrome doesn't support cookies on file:// and localhost uris. See this so question - [Why does Chrome ignore local jQuery cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the right datetime format for it to work. 
The following should do the trick

```
function clearCookie()
{
  document.cookie = 'myCookie=; expires='+new Date(0).toUTCString() +'; path=/myPath/';
}
```

And of course you need to specify the exact same path and&or domain specified on cookie creation.

Comment: It works exactly like it should as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cWshc/2/ - if you can't make it work you are probably not setting the right path or domain or similar.

Comment: same issue for me. Chrome is not deleting cookies when i run the clearCookie function provided.

Comment: For me this works if I use .toGMTString() (I've not tried toUTCString())

Comment: To quote MDN: toGMTString is deprecated and should no longer be used, it's only there for backwards compatibility, use toUTCString instead. (they will give you the same output)

Answer (score 1):

You can clear a cookie in chrome, but you need to set the domain as well when creating the blank cookie to replace the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and FF have severity problems with this. Here you can see both browsers bugs and their status is WONTFIX...

Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513

FF: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=443354