# JQuery Cookie not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I'm running this code,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function() {
                $.cookie("d", "1") ;
            }) ;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert( $.cookie("d") ) ;
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's showing '1' on Firefox, IE, but 'null' in chrome. Any idea why? I'm using latest jQuery and cookie plugin from http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chrome doesn't support cookies for locals unless you start it with the --enable-file-cookies flag. You can read a discussion about it at [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535)

*Chrome does support cookies if you use the local IP address (127.0.0.1) directly. so in the localhost case, that could be an easier workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery Cookie does not work in Chrome Browser. So, today after hours of work I found a solution to use javascript Storage API to accomplish this. You can check [This Post](http://www.gitarani.com/classified.htm?classifiedId=15360) to know details.