# Chrome not setting cookie path to root

Tags: javascript, browser, cookies

**I am setting a cookie in Javascript using the following code :**

```
setCookie('cart_items','product_name');


function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

But the cookie path is not set to root (/) in Chrome. Instead it gets set to the path from where the web page is being executed !!

I tested with IE and FF. It works fine with both these browsers ....

**What might be wrong with Chrome or Is it the problem with cookie creation code i am using??**

*In Chrome ( 16.0.912.63 )*

**Path: /xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx**

*in FF ( 6.0 )*

**Path: /**

*in IE (9)*

**Path: /**

Comment: Why don't you set the path yerself?

Comment: the path has been explicitly set ( document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; )

Comment: are you testing with local files or on server? Chrome had some issues with cookies and local files

Comment: have just tried on 15.0.874.102 Linux and it worked fine...

Comment: i am testing on a local wamp server. not yet tested with live linux server. i am going to give it a try :-)

Comment: yessssss... works on my hosting server at godaddy... but still no success at localhost !!

Comment: i am having a similar issue on a proper server with set-cookie headers. on chrome, when first visiting the site on /foo then a set-cookie with path=/ will end up stored with path=/foo. ff honors the path attribute as expected.

any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason this happens is because chrome doesn't allow setting cookies on local files by default. See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/347997/1324019 (text from answer)

> Chrome doesn't support cookies for local files (or, like Peter Lyons mentioned, localhost*) unless you start it with the --enable-file-cookies flag. You can read a discussion about it at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535.
>
> *Chrome *does* support cookies if you use the local IP address (127.0.0.1) directly. so in the localhost case, that could be an easier workaround.

Comment: ^ above is correct answer. if only OP would mark it as such