# Where are cookies saved for a local HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created an HTML file on my desktop and added some JavaScript to set and clear cookies.

Now my question is, will the cookie be saved in my browser? Can I read it back?

if Yes,

- For which domain will it be saved?
- How can I see it in Google Chrome? (HTML run on Chrome)

Comment: Unfortunately some browsers including Google Chrome do not store cookies from local web pages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies

Comment: In Opera you can view and edit cookies in the settings-page. Worth a shot (unless you have to use Chrome)

Comment: actually I am going to use that HTML file for my own chrome extension..
fortunately setting cookie works there.. it uses extension ID instead of domain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately some browsers including Google Chrome do not store cookies from local web pages:

- [Why does Chrome ignore local jQuery cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies)

Firefox has great developer plugins for cookie management, which report their domains, access paths and expiry:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/view-cookies/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/ (Personal Favourite - Requires FireBug)

For local development purposes you can setup a development domain like "localhost" or "myfakedomain.com" and run your files on a local server.

Search:

- Editing Hosts File [operating system]
- Setup Local server on [operating system] (I use xampp)

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the 'site' on a local webserver then it should be stored in your browser under 'localhost'. If however you're just opening a static HTML file Chrome will not store the cookie.

In Chrome you can use the Chrome Developer Tools and look under the 'Resources' tab.

Comment: I have not created any site. I have just created an html file..I don't know if its running under `local webserver`, I am just double clicking the html file and it runs on my default browser..

Comment: I don't find anything under `Resources` tab

Comment: In which case you [won't have the cookies stored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies) as per crolpa's comment above.