# How to read/write cookies for local file:/// HTML document?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cookies, setcookie

How can I read/write cookies for local `file:///` HTML document using Javascript or jQuery?

I tried this one >>

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays)
{
  var exdate = new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value = escape(value) + 
    ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
  var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++)
  {
    x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
    x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    if (x == c_name)
    {
      return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 13):

It depends on your browser. Chrome e.g. doesn't allow cookies for local files. see: [where cookie saved for local HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602833/where-cookie-saved-for-local-html-file)

Answer (score 8):

This will work locally

---

```
// save data value

localStorage.setItem("name", "John");

// retrieve data value

var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
```

[Original answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19211862/1680301)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

If you need multiple values stored in it try this:

https://github.com/tantau-horia/jquery-SuperCookie

Comment: I'm using the latest version of this https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie on google chrome and it works fine when the page is served from a running server on a port (i.e. localhost://9000 ) but when I open an index.html file that loads the page as a `file:///index.html` it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to loading the page from file, you can run a webserver and load the page from localhost. Apache comes with OSX and Ubuntu. Once you have set that up you will be able to use cookies on the local page.

Answer (score -2):

Try in different browser mozilla allows local storage cookies