# how to get the selected drop down value after update or refresh the page

Tags: ajax

**how to get the selected drop down value after update or refresh the page,if i update the selected drop down value after refresh the page the drop down value will be updated previous one**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">State</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis" id="cstate"><?php
                if (isset($s_state)) {
                    echo $s_state;
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6"> 
                <div class="profile-edit col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 aj-textsix"> 
                    <?php if (empty($s_state[0]) || empty($s_state)): ?> 
                        Add 
                    <?php else: ?> 
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit 
                    <?php endif; ?> 
                </div> 
            </a> 

        </div>
        <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                        <label class="col-md-4">State</label> 
                        <div class="col-md-8"> 
                            <select  id="state" name="state"  value="<?= (isset($s_state)) ? $s_state : null; ?>">
                                <option value="data1" selected="selected">Data 1</option>
                                <option value="data2">Data 2</option>
                            </select>                                                       
                            <input type="hidden" name="save_state" id="save_state" value="<?= (empty($s_state[0]) || empty($s_state)) ? 'Save' : 'Update'; ?>"> 
                            <?php if (empty($s_state[0]) || empty($s_state)): ?> 
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btnsix" data-target="#collapse6" data-toggle="collapse">Save</button> 
                            <?php else: ?> 
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btnsix" data-target="#collapse6" data-toggle="collapse">Update</button> 
                            <?php endif; ?> 
                            <button type="button" data-target="#collapse6" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

how to get the selected drop down value after update or refresh the page,if i update the selected drop down value after refresh the page the drop down value will be updated previous one

```
$(".aj-textsix").html(result.replace_textsix);
$(".aj-text-btnsix").html(result.btn_textsix);
$("#save_state").val(result.save_state);
$('#cstate').text($("#state").val());
```

Comment: save variable to `$('select').change(function(e){console.log($(this))})` and use `sessionStorage` to save the variable onchange, then check for it and inject on load https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211768/saving-a-javascript-variable-for-later-usage

Comment: i am not getting if u possible edit my code @admcfajn

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

                    $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
                        console.log(form_data);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_company_insert_update',
                            data: form_data,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (result)