# Cookies not recording

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using Notepad++ to practice my javascript.  I'm working on cookies. I visited many sites about cookies, when I write name for these cookies, they are recorded, no problem.
When I open my notepad documents with Chrome, I copied the codes from a website that works but it won't record my cookie.
Is this because my page isn't online?
Thanks

Comment: Check your javascript console to see if there are any errors/warnings

Comment: Check this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992494/how-to-read-write-cookies-for-local-file-html-document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992494/how-to-read-write-cookies-for-local-file-html-document)