# Cookies with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set cookies in an easy code example, but they don't work as I expect. The problem is that the code doesn't work, it never says "Welcome again Nemo!" Can you help me please? What i am doing wrong? Thank you very much for your time!!!

```
  <script>

        function getCookie() {

            var name = document.cookie.split('=')
            if (name[1] != "" && name[1] != null){
                return name[1];
            }else{
                return "";
            }
        }

        function checkCookie() {
            var username=getCookie();
            if (username!="") {
                alert("Welcome again " + username);
            }
            else{
                username = prompt("Please enter your name:");
                if (username != "" && username != null) {
                    document.cookie =  "Username=" + username;
                }
            }
        }

        checkCookie();

    </script>
```

Comment: [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) doesn't give back exactly what you assign to it. Retrieving its value will give you a string with all accessible cookie names/values delimited by semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use cookies in a local file using chrome? It's not allowed, see: [How to read/write cookies for local file:/// HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992494/how-to-read-write-cookies-for-local-file-html-document) and [Why does Chrome ignore local jQuery cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies)

Comment: S/He has to use a web server, whether a local or online one :)

Comment: Oh my god it was driving me crazy, thank you very much, I've tried with FireFox and its working fine, thank you really really much!

Comment: Your welcome. Also take the @jonathan-lonowski comment to get your code working.