# Saving an integer locally in p5

Tags: javascript, integer, p5.js, saving-data

Okay, so I've looked everywhere and can't find a usable answer. I'm on an iMac using p5 and I need to be able to save (by pressing a key, for example) and load (at the start of the program) an integer. If no value is set, make it 0. I don't care what format the integer is saved in, whether it be a text file or any other file type. I've tried using save(), but there's no way to load the contents afterward. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P5.js doesn't have anything specific for this. You'll have to use regular JavaScript.

You should start a search for "JavaScript save data to file" for a ton of results.

One simple and commonly used option is to use [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

To write:

```
document.cookie = 'value=' + yourValueHere + '; expires=18 Dec 2017 12:00:00 UTC'
```

Then to read:

```
var yourValueHere = document.cookie.substring(6);
```

That's just a very basic example, but hopefully it gets you on the right path. Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure this works in p5? Or just HTML javaScript?

Comment: @user8340815 P5.js **is** JavaScript. You can write plain old JavaScript in P5.js. In fact, it would be more accurate to say that you're writing P5.js inside plain old JavaScript, as P5.js is really just a JavaScript library. And yes, I just tested it to confirm that it works in P5.js.

Comment: Could you give the full code? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @user8340815 The code in my post pretty much is the full code. If you can't get it working, please post a [mcve] and explain exactly how you're runing your code.

Comment: @user8340815 Also note that this won't work if you're just opening a local `.html` file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992494/how-to-read-write-cookies-for-local-file-html-document

Comment: **Also note that this won't work if you're just opening a local `.html` file** You mean when it's run in the browser?

Comment: @user8340815 No. I mean when the url starts with `file://`.

Comment: Oops, I realized the issue. I was accidentally using `size()` instead of `createCanvas()`