# How can I save a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to save a cookie and then load it again

I have this code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var myCookies = {};

            function saveCookies()
            {
                myCookies["_uuser"] = document.getElementById("user").value;
                myCookies["_uuage"] = document.getElementById("age").value;
                //Start Reuseable Section
                document.cookie = "";
                var expiresAttrib = new Date(Date.now()+60*1000).toString();
                var cookieString = "";
                for (var key in myCookies)
                {
                    cookieString = key+"="+myCookies[key]+";"+expiresAttrib+";";
                    document.cookie = cookieString;
                }
                //End Reuseable Section
                document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = document.cookie;
            }

            function loadCookies()
            {
                //Start Reuseable Section
                myCookies = {};
                var kv = document.cookie.split(";");
                for (var id in kv)
                {
                    var cookie = kv[id].split("=");
                    myCookies[cookie[0].trim()] = cookie[1];
                }
                //End Reuseable Section
                document.getElementById("user").value = myCookies["_uuser"];
                document.getElementById("age").value = myCookies["_uuage"];
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        User: <input type="text" id="user">
        Age: <input type="text" id="age">
        <button onclick="saveCookies()">Save To Cookies</button>
        <button onclick="loadCookies()">Load From Cookies</button>
        <p id="out"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I type an input for both name and age, and click on save to cookies,
and then clock on load from cookies, I got this "undefined" for both user and age!!

what's missing in my code, so I can save the cookie

Comment: your example works well. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome cookies can only be set, when the page is running on a webserver.
For example accessed via `http://localhost/foo/bar.html` or `http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar.html`

**edit**: you might check out as well this answer:
[where cookie saved for local HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602833/where-cookie-saved-for-local-html-file)
I just tested it myself: it works with Firefox.

Otherwise it would be better for testing such cases, to put up a local webserver like [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/)

Comment: I just dragged the file to the google chrome, just like what my friend did, and it worked with him

Comment: @khaled check out my edited answer. it works with firefox (in a real webpage, hosted on a server, it will work with chrome as well)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code from a web server and it works fine.

You must load it from a web server, rather from the local file system.

JSFiddle is here if you want to prove it for yourself.

https://jsfiddle.net/brx5ropp/

Note that due to JSFiddle limitations I had to move the click triggers for the buttons to code like this:

```
document.getElementById("load").addEventListener("click", loadCookies);
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", saveCookies);
```

...but that is irrelevant to my answer!