# I can't get cookies using $cookies.get('key') of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cookies

JavaScript code

```
$cookies.put('test', 'test_value');
console.log('cookie value: ' + $cookies.get('test'));
```

I directly doubled click the html file to visit it by [file:///C:/Users/xxxxx/test.html](http://file:///C:/Users/firej/nginx-1.13.1/html/ejulezhu/users/frame_mine.html) but I found it cannot write or read the cookie:

> cookie value: undefined

If I put the html file into the 'HTML' folder of Nginx and visit it by http://127.0.0.1/test.html, I can read the cookie normally:

> cookie value: test_value

I don't know why and want to know a explanation. Thx.

Comment: What is the version of angular-cookies you are using..?

Comment: @undefined 1.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load your page via file:// most browsers won't let you interact with cookies, you need to serve the page from a local webserver.

[See this previous StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602833/where-cookie-saved-for-local-html-file)