# Why $cookieStore.get() is not working to get the value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm  testing the cookies of angularjs. Am I wondering why it's returning undefined in the console? When I set or save value using the $cookieStore.put() is working then when in getting the value from the cookie it's returning undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head  runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']).controller('MyController', ['$scope','$cookieStore', function($scope, $cookieStore) {

            $scope.WriteCookie = function() {           
                $cookieStore.put('visited', $scope.yes);                
                console.log($cookieStore.get('visited'));
            }       

            $scope.ReadCookie = function() {
                $cookieStore.get('visited');
                console.log($cookieStore.get('visited'));
            }

        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <form>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">      
    <input type="button" value="Write Cookie" ng-click="WriteCookie()" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="yes" />

    <input type="button" value="Read Cookie" ng-click="ReadCookie()" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="cookie" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have an opening `<html>` tag

Comment: @Phil just the same nothing happens it's undefined.

Comment: Seems to work just fine ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/hqbFDzuCB1N9ZTUsq321?p=preview. I did add `$scope.cookie = $cookieStore.get('visited')` so you could see the value

Comment: weird on my local machine, nothing happen

Comment: You never assign it to `$scope.cookie` in order to pass it to `ng-model`. Beyond that it works fine

Comment: @charlietfl just the same it's undefined $scope.ReadCookie = function() {
    $scope.cookie = $cookieStore.get('visited');
    console.log($cookieStore.get('visited'));
   }

Comment: Note that $cookieStore was deprecated in `1.4` ... try upgrade and use `$cookies` perhaps.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore

Comment: sorry, but the required version is 1.3.9

Comment: @Chuck are you loading the page via `file:///`? Possible duplicate of [Why does Chrome ignore local jQuery cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

update cookie version 1.6.6 and use $cookies instead of $cookieStore

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('myController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {

  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');

  console.log('favoriteCookie', favoriteCookie);

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code two ways. Opening it as file and from server. In the first case I get 'undefined' whereas in second case it reads the cookie as expected. I did some digging and looks like some browser including Chrome does not allow setting cookies for a page opened as a file. [More info ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602833/where-cookie-saved-for-local-html-file)

Comment: this is a funny situation, first I open the file directly not using localhost but when I run it on a localhost it works!

Comment: looks like you are unblocked then.