# Error in getting cookie value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to add and retrieve cookie using JavaScript. My code is

```js
   function setCookie(name,value,days) {
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();            
                    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + ";";
                    alert("Hello you are : "+getCookie(name)); // displaying alert message 'Hello you are :'
            }
            function getCookie(cname) { //any problem with this code?
                var rcookies = document.cookie;
                var cookiearray = rcookies.split(";");
                for (i=0;i<cookiearray.length;i++){
                    var value=cookiearray[i];
                    value=value.split("=");
                if(value[0]==cname){
                    return value[1];
                }
                }
                return "";
            }
    
    function checkCookie() {
        var user = getCookie("user");
        if (user != "") {
            alert("You are " + user); // This alert is Never displayed But it need to be. 
        } else {
            user = document.getElementById("name").value;
            alert(user); // displaying the value of text field
            setCookie("user", user, 1);
        }
    }
```

```html
    <form>
     <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required">
     <input type="button" onclick="checkCookie();" id="buttons" name="button" value="cookie">
    </form>
```

The problem is when I click on the button it set the cookie(I saw it in 'view site information', it was there) But when I try to get the cookie using `getCookie` method it's not showing the cookie value saved in cookies. And also when I refresh the page and press the 'view site information' icon to see cookie again, it shows 0 cookies there.
what's wrong with the code? Or any mistake I'm doing?

Comment: Why do you keep editing the code? Please do this before posting your question and make sure the problem reproduces with the code that you post. The code works: https://jsfiddle.net/d0p6gooz/

Comment: You should not put the button in the `form` element, or it will submit the form.

Comment: Sorry Sir, Now we are with the final code. No further editing is required. I copied the actual code

Comment: I also tried to with button tag still it's not showing the value of the cookie

Comment: It works for me in the fiddle. Did you try it? There must be something else wrong in your code that you have not supplied in the question.

Comment: can anyone tell me how can I do it with form tag..???

Comment: I added it to my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button submits the form. If you don't need to submit a form, then don't use the `form` tag, or else put the button outside of it. Alternatively, cancel the default action of a button click.

With this HTML (without `form`) it works fine:

```
<input id="name"><button onclick="checkCookie()">Check</button>
```

See it run in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0p6gooz/)

If you need the `form` tag, then cancel the default effect of the click by adding `return false` in the `onclick` attribute:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required">
    <input type="button" onclick="checkCookie();return false;" id="buttons" name="button" value="cookie">
</form>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0p6gooz/1/).

#### Local files

When you access your web page via the `file://` protocol, the support for cookies is not guaranteed: it depends on the browser. Check out:

- [Where are cookies saved for a local HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8602914/5459839)

So make sure to place your web page on a web server. You can install one on your PC in case you don't want to actually place it on the internet.

Alternatively, you could decide to use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead of cookies. That has better support for `file://` protocol, and has an easier syntax anyway.

Comment: Sorry, Its a typing mistake. Actually its 0 in actual code. I will edit this one.

Comment: Yes, It's working in jsfiddle, but I don't know why, when I'm running the same code locally it's doing the same as before.

Comment: You'll need to provide something that is reproducible.

Comment: I'm working on a polling website. when a user attempts the poll, I want to check whether he has attempted it before or not using cookies. The code is already given in the question asked.

Comment: Yes, This also working in jsfiddle. But why it's not working when I'm running the same code in a local file saved on my computer? I don't know what actually I'm doing wrong in this. But thanks man for your attempts.

Comment: Cookie support for local file is lacking in some browsers by default. See addition to my answer.

Comment: Bro, Thanks a lot for your help. Actually, at the end, I will run this code in JSP project. I was just trying to first make a local file test if it's working then include it in the mainstream. Your suggestion worked, I just pasted the same code in a JSP file and its working. Thanks, man.

Comment: Oohh yes, why not.