# Facebook PHP SDK v4.0 FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper return state NULL

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Im working on my localhost, using FB PHP SDK 4.0. I was able to complete the login using JS SDK, now Im trying to access some info via PHP SDK.

On each page I add this js and php code.

**JavaScipt**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'app-id',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.1',        
    status     : true,
    cookie     : true

  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
};

(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

**PHP**

```
session_start();
//NO COMPOSER
require '/path-to/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app-id', 'app-secret');

$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
try {
   $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
if ($session) {
  // Logged in.
}
```

On JavaScript whenever I call the FB.getLoginStatus() it gives me a success response. However on the PHP side whenever I dump the `$helper` it returns with `["state"]=> NULL`. I made sure my app-id matches.

I thought that they communicate through a `cookie` but when I view my browser Cookies and Site data I cant find anything relevant. Or do I need an access token to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

It's working when I tested on Firefox. This is actually an issue with Chrome: **Google Chrome does not support cookies for local files (including localhost) unless you start it with the --enable-file-cookies flag. Chrome does, however, support cookies if you use your local IP address—127.0.0.1— for testing.**

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10081969/1158909