# Facebook session from javascript facebook inlog cookie is null

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, session, facebook-sdk-4.0

For my application i need to get some basic user information from Facebook profiles. I made a JavaScript file which handles the log in button and a PHP file which handles the acquisition of data. the PHP file uses the FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper for the session.

The problem that i have is that the Facebook session is NULL and because of that this error appears whenever i request data: ***Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given, called in \mypath\FacebookRequest.php***. I am using a localhost xammp apache server on https.
These are my php and JavaScript files.

### JavaScript file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script>    
        function statusChangeCallback(response) 
        {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);              
            if (response.status === 'connected') 
                {
                    // User is connected to app and facebook
                } 
                else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
                {
                    // User is only logged into Facebook
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // User has not logged in to Facebook
                }
        }


        function checkLoginState() 
        {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
        {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
        if (response.status === 'connected')
        {
            window.location="phpfile.php";
        }

        });
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
        {
            FB.init(
            {
                appId      : 'My_app_ID',
                cookie     : true,  
                xfbml      : true,  
                version    : 'v2.1', 
                status     : true
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
            {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) 
        {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
        (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<fb:login-button max_rows="3" size="xlarge" show_faces="true" auto_logout_link="true"default_audience="everyone" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

### PHPfile

```
   <?php
    require_once "/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php";

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('myappid', 'myappsecret');

    $helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
    try 
    {
        $session = $helper->getSession();
        if($session === NULL)
        {
            echo "Session = null ";
        }
    } 
    catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) 
    {
        // facebookerror
    } 
    catch(\Exception $ex) 
    {

    }
    if ($session) 
    {
        echo "session sucessfull";
    }

    ?>
```

When i run the code and the $session variable is checked in the phpfile it will be null and it will output the message i made.
**My question is: why is my $session variable null in my php file?**

Thanks in advance!

Related question:

[Facebook PHP SDK v4.0 FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper return state NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155019/facebook-php-sdk-v4-0-facebookjavascriptloginhelper-return-state-null)

Comment: Is it just broken code demonstration? Or what is your question?

Comment: Can you whittle this down a minimal code-set that replicates your issue?

Comment: My question is: why is my $session variable null in my php file?

Comment: Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155019/facebook-php-sdk-v4-0-facebookjavascriptloginhelper-return-state-null