# JQuery show/hide div toggle stay open after refresh

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, refresh

I have a chat box in the bottom right of my website, that opens and closes no problem.  It is hidden by default, and then when you click on "chat" it stays open!  My problem is that I would want the chatbox to stay open when a user changes pages until they decide to minimize it again.  At the moment, if you change pages the chatbox minimizes itself.  Can someone help?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {
    jQuery('#initiallyHidden').toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
#chatbox {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}

#initiallyHidden {
  bottom: 100;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chatbox"><input type="button" id="hideshow" value="Quick Chat" class="tbox" />
  <br>
  <div id="initiallyHidden" style="display: none;">Content</div>
```

Above is the scripts all used for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that [Cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is needed to be used to persist the user preferences for the current session. So when page is rendered, check the initial state and update state with every click.
The example of using cookies can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery).
So the example will look like this (using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var chatVisible = 'chatVisible';
  var chatElement = $('#initiallyHidden');
  var getCookie = function() {
    return JSON.parse(Cookies.get(chatVisible) || 'false');
  };
  var setCookie = function(value) {
    Cookies.set(chatVisible, value)
  };
  var visible = getCookie();
  chatElement.toggle(visible);
  setCookie(visible);

  $('#hideshow').on('click', function() {
    var visible = !getCookie();
    setCookie(visible);
    chatElement.toggle(visible);
  });
});
```

```css
#chatbox {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}

#initiallyHidden {
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@beta/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<div id="chatbox">
  <input type="button" id="hideshow" value="Quick Chat" class="tbox" />
</div>
<br>
<div id="initiallyHidden" style="display: none;">
  Content
</div>
```

Please note, that cookies in chrome work properly when you use web server to serve your files, not just opening the file. If you need that possibility, please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13801262/8013693). Firefox is OK with serving cookies even for static files.

Comment: Thank you @Roman So would I in this case need to replace the "chatVisible" entry within the Jquery to the div that I have? (initiallyHidden)

Comment: Sorry, Didn't tag properly.

Comment: Cookie is a sort of key-value data storage, which is held inside the browser for every site. According to the [examples](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/) cookie can be set by `$.cookie("key", "value");` and got by `$.cookie("key");`. So in my example "chatVisible" is only a key, that refers to the settings bound to the chat. I created variable `var chatVisible = 'chatVisible';` to avoid mistypings while typing key name multiple times. Element operations are performed on `var chatElement = jQuery('#hideshow');` DOM element, so you can change this variable.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, so updated the answer, and now `var chatElement = jQuery('#hideshow');` is fixed and looks like `var chatElement = jQuery('#initiallyHidden');`.

Comment: I have entered the code but unfortunately it no longer opens or closes the div

Comment: Updated the example and tested it locally. Also added tags for script and style section.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the chat window state between pages, you will need to persist the state somewhere.

For example, when the user opens the chat, you could set a cookie to store the new state. When loading each page, you would check the cookie for the current state (open / closed) and default if no cookie is available.

Comment: I thought that may be the case Fenton, thanks.  I will take a look around and see if I can find anything to help me along the way