# Why are all my jQuery cookies turning up undefined?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cookies, undefined

I've sourced jQuery, the jQuery Cookie Plugin, and my own Javascript (in that order) at the end of the body of my page.  What I'm unable to grasp is why my cookie won't read when I `console.log` the cookie, or when I assign it to a variable and `console.log` the variable.  Also, when I open the page in Chrome and look through the Resources>Cookies section, it shows that my page has created no cookies.

Also, the problem may have to do with my operating on the file locally.  It isn't hosted yet.  Everything is just sitting on my drive, not in the internet yet.

Here's my code:

```
$.cookie('testcookie',1,{expires: 5, path:'/'});
console.log($.cookie('testcookie'));
var variable=$.cookie('testcookie');
console.log(variable);
```

That function should log '1' in the console twice, but just gives me two instances of `undefined`.

I've checked my HTML four times now, and I'm 100% sure the sources for my scripts are pointed to the correct place.  I've also made sure the function is being called correctly, etc.  I've checked all the probable problems, but I just can't find anything wrong.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you noticed that you're missing an end quote at the second line of your sample code? Is that just a typo or a copy of your app code?

Comment: Just a typo.  Not in my actual code.  Thanks for pointing that out, fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Chrome ignore local jQuery cookies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, it sounds like it is because it's hosted locally.

See: [Why does Chrome ignore local jQuery cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies?rq=1)

Comment: That turned out to be it!  Thank you for the help!

Comment: On a Vagrant / Symfony app this turned out to be true of :8080/app_dev.php  as well! Thank you so much.