# Why jQuery.cookie plugin returns “[object Object]”

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, phonegap-build

I'm using the [plugin jQuery.cookie by carhartl](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) on my phonegap build project. However when I try to create a cookie and then read it, it return a null value : [object Object].

Here is the code :

```
$(".validator").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://path/to/adduser.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){

        $.cookie('name', 'yolo', { path: '/' });
        alert($.cookie()); 
    });
 });
```

Do you have any idea to help me resolve my problem ?

Comment: Because it is an object. To get the name, just call $.cookie('name').

Comment: Pass the name of the cookie when getting a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the cookie name to read it:

```
alert($.cookie('name'));
```

Comment: `alert($.cookie('name'));` Return : **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

The readme file, available in the git repository linked in the question, shows that the `cookie()` method returns an object:

```
$.cookie(); // => { "name": "value" }
```

The `alert()` method doesn't know anything about what the object contains, which is why it is displaying `[object Object]`. You need to instead use `$.cookie('name')` to point to the specific value stored inside the object.

Comment: `alert($.cookie('name'));` Return : **undefined**

Answer (score 0):

I found out.

It is because I use google chrome to test my app which ignore local jQuery cookies.

Thanks.

Cf

[why-are-all-my-jquery-cookies-turning-up-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946625/why-are-all-my-jquery-cookies-turning-up-undefined)

[why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies?rq=1)

Comment: But even if you resolve that, you still need to put the cookie name in the call.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, ticked.