# Can't access existing php cookie

Tags: php

I'm developing a website on my localhost which uses cookies. I have a function that generates a random, 25 character string which will be stored in a database and set as a referential cookie on the user's browser.

I've searched the internet and this site, but wasn't able to find a solution for my problem.

Below an overview of the related code

```
function generateRandomString($length){
    $string = "";
    $possible = "012346789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW";
    $maxlength = strlen($possible);
    if($length > $maxlength){
        $length = $maxlength;
    }
    $i = 0; 
    while($i < $length){ 
        $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, $maxlength-1), 1);
        if(!strstr($string, $char)){ 
            $string .= $char;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $string;
}

$uCookie = generateRandomString(25);

setcookie('uHash', $uCookie, time()+60*60*24*30);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('
    UPDATE User 
    SET u_UserCookie = :cookie 
    WHERE u_UserId = :id
'); 

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':cookie' => $uCookie,
    ':id' => $user_id
));
```

Now when i try `echo($_COOKIE['uHash']);` i get an empty string.

The strange part is that when i check my chrome preferences, the cookie does exists

```
Name:    uHash
Content:    134uHnEPrCmBNGqeAjhRSUiJL
Domain: localhost
Path:   /~path/to/login
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   Yes
Created:    Wednesday, April 17, 2013 4:21:27 PM
Expires:    Friday, May 17, 2013 4:21:27 PM
```

The string '134uHnEPrCmBNGqeAjhRSUiJL' can also be found in the database, so that works

Am i missing some basic info about cookies (on a localhost)?

**SOLVED**

The problem is, according to php.net

> 'that domain names must contain at least two dots (.), hence 'localhost' is invalid and the browser will refuse to set the cookie'

So i solved it by doing this

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
setcookie('uHash', $uCookie, time()+60*60*24*30, '/', $domain, false);
```

Comment: Are you trying to read `$_COOKIE` in the same script that set it?

Comment: Are you using chrome?

Comment: Nope, it's not on the same page. The cookie is set in a login page and i try to display the cookie value on the index page without any result. And yes, i'm using Chrome

Comment: In chrome cookies are restricted from local use. Acces your website through 127.0.0.1/ rather than through localhost/ to work a way around chrome's behaviours. Also check this question on SO: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies/6468432#6468432)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this issue:
[Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain)

Domain names in a cookie must contain two dots. Localhost therefor is invalid.

Comment: Weird... The OP doesn't set a domain in `setcookie()`and he also claimed that the browser actually accepts the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you're trying to access the cookie in the right path/domain :

```
 setcookie ('uHash', $uCookie, time()+60*60*24*30, /path/of/the/website, false);
```

You need to redirect to having the headers sending your cookie before you can catch it.

See [setcookie doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Answer (score 0):

We don't have all the relevant code but I guess it looks like this:

```
setcookie('uHash', $uCookie, time()+60*60*24*30);
echo $_COOKIE['uHash'];
```

From [the manual](http://es2.php.net/setcookie):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the **next** page
>   load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

If you absolutely need it on the same page, you can probably do this:

```
setcookie('uHash', $uCookie, time()+60*60*24*30);
$_COOKIE['uHash'] = $uCookie;
echo $_COOKIE['uHash'];
```

Comment: Nope, it's not on the same page. The cookie is set in a login page and i try to display the cookie value on the index page without any result