# JQuery plugin use gives "undefined" error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, jquery-cookie

Chrome on Rails on Localhost. Here's a trimmed version of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="blahblah=" name="csrf-token" />
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body data-action='index' data-controller='application'>
</body>
```

In the Chrome console (and in scripts farther down), `$.cookie` is undefined and `$.cookie("a", "b")` throws an error.

I've tried a few other CDNs, but same issue.

Edit:
I'm trying things out in the Chrome Javascript console, which (I presume) runs after page load. I can check the "Resources" tab and see that the plugin has been loaded without issue. If I rearrange to link the plugin prior to Jquery, I get expected errors.

Comment: Make sure that you do it after the JavaScript has been loaded (document ready): http://jsfiddle.net/cq9m8/

Comment: Are you using `http://localhost` or `file://localhost`? Since your URLs don't have an "http:" prefix, they inherit the protocol used for the containing page.

Comment: Provide the code snippet / block that contains $.cookie

Comment: In the Chrome Javascript console: `$.cookie("a", "b")`

Comment: Barmar: Not specifying, but usually HTTP. I changed the src addresses to specify the protocol, but no go.

Comment: What does `$.fn.jquery` give you? (to confirm something isn't overwriting `$`)

Comment: JavaScript cookies don't work in Chrome on `localhost`. Not sure if that could relate to this or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies

Comment: try using `http://127.0.0.1` instead

Comment: @matthewpavkov Chrome accepts cookies from a web server on localhost but not when the page is served as a local file.

OP: Could you provide the code from application.js?

Comment: Purely the generated file; comments comments `//require_tree .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the javascript files served by my application via the "resources" tab, and discovered that my `application.js` still had JQuery in it, so, presumably, it was redefining the JQuery without Coookie when the file was loaded.

This occurred because I switched from using gems to load JQuery to using an external CDN, but did *not* recompile (or delete) my assets.

Solved by removing the compiled assets from `public/assets`