# JQuery: cant set cookie in $(button).click

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

im kind of new to JQuery... 
I would like to save the value of a form field as a cookie once i click on the button but it does not seem to work. The code i'm using is the following

```
$(function() {
  $("#myButtonId").click( function() {
     var myVar = $('#myTextField').val();
     $.cookie("cookie", myVar);

     //i try the next line just to control if the cookie was saved
     alert($.cookie("cookie"));
   });
});
```

When the alert pops up it just shows "undefined" as an output (meaning the cookie was not set), if i set the cookie outside the click function it works fine.

EDIT: if i may be of help... the button is the submit button to login to my web application, i want to save the login data so next time i open the application i dont have to rewrite the login data

Comment: Can you include jquery library?

Comment: What value you get for `alert($('#myTextField').val());` ?

Comment: have you included the [cookie library](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) or are there any errors in your console? Or is your button in a form - if so you may need to prevent it's default action

Comment: let me answer... 
1) im using the https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie library
2) i dont have any errors on the console
3) what do you mean by: prevent the button default action? (yes, it makes part of a form)
4) The value i get is "undefined"

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be solely within the snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/udcktn1v/. Are you accessing the page via `http://`? If you're trying with `file://`, [browsers won't typically save cookies with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies).

Comment: Actually im launching the application in local, could that be a reason?

Comment: Anyone? im convinced this is an easy thing to solve, it's just that i lack the knowledge about JQuery