# Styleswitcher doesn't work on chrome just firefox. why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have implemented a styleswitcher. but it only works on firefox.
I want to run this also on chrome, IE etc.

styleswitcher.js

http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/styleswitcher/styleswitcher.js

head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/styleswitcher.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css" title="default">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style1.css" title="darkblue">
```

body

```
<a href="/" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('darkblue'); return false;">darkblue</a>
<a href="/" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default'); return false;">Default</a>
```

I think, I can't save the cookie on chrome, but I don't know why.

Comment: Are you testing locally or on a server?

Comment: I am testing it locally

Comment: Chrome doesn't support cookies for local files unless you start it with the `--enable-file-cookies flag` See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies

Comment: Thank you for the answer.that means, that it would work if I save the file on a webserver?

Comment: You can either start Chrome specifying `--enable-file-cookies`, install a server stack locally (e.g. xampp.org), or upload your files via FTP to a remote server (typically shared hosting).