# Javascript cant read cookie in Chrome but works in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cookies

I am using a javascript function to read a cookie and it works in IE but not chrome. Why won't chrome work?

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: are you testing on your local?

Comment: your `else` needs opening and closing brackets (dunno if that'll fix anything, but it just needs em:)

Comment: yes. testing on local

Comment: the opening and closing brackets did not make a difference.

Comment: ran it locally on Chrome and working fine. Are you getting any console error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies

It works as long as I don't use local host.