# Unable to set cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I'm trying to set my cookies in Javascript the following way

```
<video id = 'media'></video>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
   document.cookie='X-At=$ACCESS_TOKEN$';
   document.getElementById('media').src = "$some video link$";
});
```

However, the cookie just doesn't seem to be added. The file is also hosted on a simpleHttpServer because Chrome seems to ignore pages on local pages. Could someone tell me where the problem is? Note that the cookie gets set when I delete `document.getElementById('media').src = "$some video link$";`... SoI'm guessing it has to do with setting the source of the element.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you sure the code is running in the first place? If you set a breakpoint or add an alert, do they fire?

Comment: You're missing a `)` after `}`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I'm inspecting all the elements/functions as they're invoked.

Comment: Just tested it, it works for me. http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/test.html

Comment: @Barmar Weirdest thing ever.. I have the same exact thing..

Comment: Regarding cookies on local pages, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies

Comment: @Barmar Thanks so much for the help! I think this might be the issue. See Edit!

Comment: I added that to my test page, it still sets the cookie. But I didn't give a real video link, could that make a difference?

Comment: @Barmar Yes and I'm not exactly sure why...

Comment: I tried putting a real URL there, I still get the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that cookies are domain specific. So I was unable to set the cookies for the request to a different network, i.e. my file is hosted on a local network 127.0.0.1 and I was trying to send the cookie to a different domain.

The hacky go around for this was to create a proxy server for my request and overwrite the cookie there and redirect the target to my original destination. Couldn't think of a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

mate: way of create a cookie like this

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Comment: The expiration time is optional. His code works as it is.