# Jquery and cookie - Update of the first start but not after

Tags: js-cookie

Please,

I don't know upgrading one existing cookie.
I tryed with the code in below but don't worked.
He isn't upgrading array length but $.listImages.length return correct number.

My Jquery version is 1.12.

```
var list = [];
  for (var i = 12; i >= 0; i--) {          
    var image = {
      id:"f6183197-7925-45a8-bafb-7e13c69686a9",
      name:"CACHOEIRO WHITE 2CM Block 01000775 Bundle  Slab 005",
      path:"FOTOS - 2016\\02 - FEVEREIRO\\CACHOEIRO WHITE\\CACHOEIRO WHITE01000775-2CM\\",
      thumbnail:null,
      dateIndex:"2016-04-28T14:42:39",
      file:"CACHOEIRO WHITE 2CM Block 01000775 Bundle  Slab 005.JPG"
    };
    list.push(image);
  }
  Cookies.set('imagesSelected', list);
  var listSaved = Cookies.get('imagesSelected');
  //Returned number 13?
  alert(listSaved);

  //Save and get again but new quantity

  list = listSaved;
  for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {          
    var image = {
      id:"f6183197-7925-45a8-bafb-7e13c69686a9",
      name:"CACHOEIRO WHITE 2CM Block 01000775 Bundle  Slab 005",
      path:"FOTOS - 2016\\02 - FEVEREIRO\\CACHOEIRO WHITE\\CACHOEIRO WHITE01000775-2CM\\",
      thumbnail:null,
      dateIndex:"2016-04-28T14:42:39",
      file:"CACHOEIRO WHITE 2CM Block 01000775 Bundle  Slab 005.JPG"
    };
    list.push(image);
  }
  listJSON = JSON.stringify(list);
  Cookies.set('imagesSelected', listJSON);
  listSaved = Cookies.getJSON('imagesSelected');
  //Returned number 16?
  alert(listSaved.length);
```

Comment: That is working, see https://jsfiddle.net/r0odz1jv/. Need to provide the version it is being used, the error and the content of the `$.listImages` property.

Also, this could be a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies/347997#347997

Comment: Oh... I am in local mode but using Iceweasel.
I will test in hosted mode.

Comment: Same problem.
It's very weird. I record an array with 14 items and when I call get returns only 9.

Comment: Am I reaching the size limit for cookies? I'm trying to write almost 3400 characters.

Comment: It could be. One should not send big chunks of data using the cookie, it should only send small tokens and pieces of information.

Comment: I think it was the same character limit.
I solved my problem using StorageAPI.

https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API

Comment: Yes, I know that not is possible send big data in the cookies but the major problem was didn't any exception return.
It was hard to find out.

Comment: Thanks, @FagnerBrack!

Comment: We have plans to add a tool to debug the cookies in the page, see the bullet points of https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/57

Answer (score 1):

I think it was the same character limit. I solved my problem using StorageAPI. [github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API](http://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API)

Not is possible send big data in the cookies but the major problem was didn't any exception return.
It was hard to find out.