# Django cookies not working on Minikube at .local domain

Tags: django, nginx, kubernetes, cookies, minikube

I have a web app on Django with simple authentication as follows:

```py
# in a request handler
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    return redirect('/')
```

The app works fine running on localhost and on real servers through HTTPS at `my-app.com` (no a real domain of course). Now I'm trying to make it running on Kubernetes and Minikube. I've set up a Deployment, Service, NginX-Ingress, also I specified `minikube ip` in my `/etc/hosts` file as `my-app.local`, and I can access it using Chrome browser, but the authentication doesn't work! Browser saves no cookies, and I always get redirected to the log in page.

And I cannot find any reason: I've checked server logs and browser network traces, they look fine, I also used `curl` to compare authentication method results of real `.com` version of the app and my minikube/`.local` version, they are pretty same, I see correct `Set-Cookie: ...` everywhere, but the cookies don't get saved in the browser. What can be the cause of this problem??

#### Update

I've changed my local domain to `test.my-app.com`, but got no improvements `:(`

#### Update 2

I turned off the Ingress, so it's not related to the problem.

In addition, I have added middleware to my Django app to log cookies of each request, and I also made a script to check what's happening:

```py
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.post(url, data={
        'username': 'some-login',
        'password': 'some-password',
    })
    response = session.get(url)
    print(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    print(session.cookies)
```

When the url is set to the real app or Django app on my localhost, I get cookies `csrftoken` and `sessionid`, and the response is showing the user's personal page. I also see the cookies in the server logs

When the url is set to the Docker/K8s/Minikube service, I get the same cookies in the script, BUT the response shows log in page again. Also, the server logs show no cookies... Looks like something related to Django cookies processing.

Comment: Try changing the TLD from `.local` to `.test` or `.lan`. See the [possible cause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/347997).

Comment: @Melvyn hi and thanks for your reply! I changed TLD to `.test` but got no difference `:(` I guess the topic that you linked is about `127.0.0.1` / `localhost` only, not about such domains...

Comment: Yep, worth a shot. I stay away from .local, cause it's reserved for ["dynamic devices" (multicast DNS / Zeroconf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local). Then the next thing is timestamps. Make sure the cookie time makes sense. And then you're pretty much out of options assuming code is identical.

Comment: @Melvyn tanks for the advice! I just looked at timestamps, and yes, they're correct... But maybe NginX-Ingress proxy eats the cookies before resending requests to the pod with Django so that cookies get reset? 

Comment: Then the request would send them. The first page after authentication should have raw request headers with Cookie: in them. And in the view or middleware you can log `request.COOKIES` to confirm they haven't arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked all the settings of Django app and found out that the `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` option was the cause of the problem, as [the doc says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE):

> If this is set to True, the cookie will be marked as “secure”, which means browsers may ensure that the cookie is only sent under an HTTPS connection.

The app is configured to use this and some other settings for security reasons when running in prod mode, and my K8s configuration was not configured to run in debug mode.